# Translate custom post type slug

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wpml

I'm using Wordpress 5 et WPML.
I have a lot of custom type.
Each custom type has his slug.

My website is in english and french

Exemple :

- [www.webtest.com/city/](http://www.webtest.com/city/)
- [www.webtest.com/country/](http://www.webtest.com/country/)

I need to translate city and country in french :

- [www.webtest.com/ville/](http://www.webtest.com/ville/)
- [www.webtest.com/pays/](http://www.webtest.com/pays/)

How can i translate the slug ?

Example of cuctom type :

```
$rewrite = array(
        'slug'                  => 'city',
        'with_front'            => true,
        'pages'                 => true,
        'feeds'                 => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Les villes', 'test' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Les villes', 'test' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-home',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
    );

    register_post_type( 'villes', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'villes_post_type', 0 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using WPML, you can achieve this with an addon for WPML.

1. Install and activate the "WPML String Translation" addon.
2. Go to WPML -> Settings
3. Under the "Slug translations" section, check "Translate custom post and taxonomy base slugs (via WPML String Translation)". [image: WPML Slug translations section]
4. On the same page, scroll down, under "Post Types Translation", find the name of your custom post type.
5. Check "Set different slugs in different languages for [post type name]" [image: different slug for different language with WPML]
6. Enter the translated post type slug for each language.
7. Click the "Save" button.